# Question about a new type of confidence interval

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, computer-science, probability, data-science

I came up with the following result, tested on many data sets, but I do not have a formal proof yet:

***Theorem***: The width L of any confidence interval is asymptotically equal (as n tends to infinity) to a power function of n, namely L=A / n^B where A and B are two positive constants depending on the data set, and n is the sample size.

See [here](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/confidence-intervals-without-pain) and [here](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/modern-re-sampling-and-statistical-recipes) for details. The B exponent seems to be very similar to the Hurst exponent in time series, not only in terms of what it represents, but also in the values that it takes: B=1/2 corresponds to perfect data (no auto-correlation or undesirable features) and B=1 corresponds to "bad data" typically with strong auto-correlations.

Note that B=1/2 is what everyone uses nowadays, assuming observations are independently and identically distributed, with an underlying normal distribution. I also devised a method to make the interval width converges faster to zero: O(1/n) rather than O(1/SQRT(n)). This is also described in section 3.3. in my article on re-sampling ([here](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/modern-re-sampling-and-statistical-recipes)) and my approach in this context seems very much related to what is called second-order accurate intervals (usually achieved with modern versions of bootstrapping, see [here](http://users.stat.umn.edu/~helwig/notes/bootci-Notes.pdf).)

My question is whether my theorem is original, ground-breaking, and correct, and how would someone prove it (or refute it.)

[Example of Confidence Interval](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8h6ej.png)

[Perl code to produce confidence intervals for the correlation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgoXu.png)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: There is some very efficient code involved, but yes, my question is not about discussing the code. I posted it on Stackexchange too, and they advised me to post it on Stackoverflow.

Comment: It would seem that your question in SE was [closed as unclear](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/406707/new-fundamental-theorem-related-to-the-lengths-of-confidence-intervals), *not* because it was more appropriate for SO (it is certainly not).

Comment: Any suggestion for a good place to post my question, outside Stackoverflow or Stackexchange? I haven't tried Reddit but I think it would not be well received on Reddit either.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is, what do you mean by confidence interval?

Let's say i do non parametric estimation of a density probability function with a kernel density estimator. 
Interval confidence has no meaning in this setting. however you can compute something which is the "speed" of convergence of your kernel density estimator to your target function. Depending on the choice of the distance you choose between function, you can get different speed of convergence. And for example, the best speed with $L^{\infty}$ distance depends on a $\log(n)$ factor.

By the way you give yourself a counterexample in your first article.

So for me your theorem can not exist for two reasons :

1. It is not clear, you need to specify exactly what you mean by confidence interval. You need to say what do you mean by depending on the dataset (does it depends on $N$ the number of observations?)
2. There is "counter example", since asymptotic speed of convergence of estimators can be more complicated than what you say.